# How to copy video from external storage to internal storage in SDK version 33?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, fileinputstream, android-internal-storage

I have a video picker and when the users picks the video, I want to copy it into the internal files folder and modify it. Is it possible? how?

If not, where can I store the video so the user can't access it (as I'm going to modify it and I don't want him to be able to access the modified video)

video picker handled by this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("video/*");
    String[] mimeTypes = {"video/mp4", "video/3gp", "video/mpeg"};
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_VIDEO_PICKER);
```

Then, its result:

```
Uri videoUri = data.getData();
```

I'm trying to copy the file using:

```
uriSrc = "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A1000099794"

destPath = getFilesDir() + "/video.mp4";

public static boolean copyFileToInternalStorage(Context context, Uri uriSrc, String destPath) {
    try {
        //InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uriSrc);
        //File tempFile = File.createTempFile("video", ".mp4", context.getCacheDir());
        //FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);

        //byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        //int read;
        //while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        //    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
        //}
        //outputStream.close();

        InputStream fileInputStream= context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uriSrc);

        FileOutputStream outputStreamInternal = new FileOutputStream(destPath);
        byte[] buffer2 = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fileInputStream.read(buffer2)) > 0) {
            outputStreamInternal.write(buffer2, 0, length);
        }
        fileInputStream.close();
        outputStreamInternal.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("file_log", "exception when copying the src file to the internal storage: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return new File(destPath).exists();
}
```

it copies the video to internal but without audio.

Comment: `a video picker` What is that? Please show the code. And tell what you get when the user picks a file.

Comment: Directly after the first while block an `outputStream.close()` is missing. You are ready then as you have a copy in the cache storage then.

Comment: `FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(tempFile);` That and all following code do not make sense. You copy a file and then you would make a copy of the copied file. Why?

Comment: Mmmm.. very confusing. It is yet diffferent. You do two copies. Not needed. Just do one copy from Uri uriSrc to String destPath. Remove the tempfile stuff.

Comment: Show with which destPath youi call copyFileToInternalStorage().

Comment: `boolean copyFileToInternalStorage` Do not name it like that as destPath determines where the file be saved. `boolean copyFileToDestination`.

Comment: Please remove the android-contentprovider tag.

Comment: Further this has nothing to do with SDK version. Code would be the same for all SDK's.

Comment: Use getFilesDir() or getExternalFilesDir() to store the copy invisible to the user with file explorer apps.

Comment: Thanks, I added explanation and outputStream.close();. I didn't remove the temp stuff as I'm not sure about the 'while' after. If possible, please paste the main code so I can see

Comment: You can do it all yourself. You copy twice instead of one time. You have two while loops. Remove the first one and the stuff around it. Then adapt the last one to copy from uri to destPath. Post your new code. You can leave your old block and make new code in new block.